# Como passar dados entre aplicativos na mesma rede?

Tags: python

Eu pretendo fazer um aplicativo personalizado pra ajudar na automação de alguns trabalhos no computador, mas ele precisa executar os comandos no celular. A parte do aplicativo em sí em sem problema algum, mas eu não tenho conhecimento em rede e não tenho ideia de como passar os dados.

Answer (score 0):

Olha eu estou criando um app e trabalho na rede local com xampp eu acho que poderia ser uma solução. E usaria HttpURLConnection para a conexão entre os apps. Mas isso é só uma ideia. Pode ser que exista uma classe para trabalhar direto com a rede. Possa ser que eu esteja falando besteira também rsrsrsrs. É só uma ideia blz.